# Go httprouter custom middleware

Tags: go

I'm relatively new as a go programmer and I'm trying to build a custom middleware for my server. The problem is that it's behavior it's not as I expected it to be. Can someone please explain why my context is not set to *ME*?

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/test", middlewareChain(contentType, name))
    log.Print("App running on 8080")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}

func middlewareChain(h ...httprouter.Handle) httprouter.Handle {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
        r = r.WithContext(context.WithValue(r.Context(), "test", "You"))
        log.Print("Set context to YOU")
        for _, handler := range h {
            handler(w, r, p)
        }
    }
}

func contentType(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
    r = r.WithContext(context.WithValue(r.Context(), "test", "Me"))
    log.Print("Set context to ME")
    header := w.Header()
    header.Set("Content-type", "application/json")
}

func name(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
    log.Printf("Context: %s", r.Context().Value("test"))
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDiaQ.jpg[image: Result]

Comment: Because [`WithContext`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.WithContext) returns a copy of `r`, and although that copy is just a *shallow* one, its Context is set to the provided argument and therefore each such copy has its own Context. The `r` copy from `contentType` is not passed to anywhere else therefore its context won't be accessible anywhere else.

Comment: Related: https://dave.cheney.net/2017/01/26/context-is-for-cancelation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find middleware most useful if they are chained with reference to the next one.  A middleware later in the stack can rely on values set by previous ones so they're order dependent.  Sometimes, they can decide to stop the stack under a condition.

How about chaining them like this?

```golang
func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/test", setTestYou(contentType(name)))
    log.Print("App running on 8080")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}

func setTestYou(next httprouter.Handle) httprouter.Handle {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
        r = r.WithContext(context.WithValue(r.Context(), "test", "You"))
        log.Print("Set context to YOU")

        if next != nil {
            next(w, r, p)
        }
    }
}

func contentType(next httprouter.Handle) httprouter.Handle {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
        if r.Header.Get("Content-type") != "application/json" {
            // break here instead of continuing the chain
            w.Status = 400
            return
        }

        r = r.WithContext(context.WithValue(r.Context(), "test", "Me"))
        log.Print("Set context to ME")
        header := w.Header()
        header.Set("Content-type", "application/json")

        if next != nil {
            next(w, r, p)
        }
    }
}

func name(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, p httprouter.Params) {
    log.Printf("Context: %s", r.Context().Value("test"))
}
```

Since they're passing the request/context into the next one, the changes will stick.